# Python2 Pygame Installation Problems OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

At first I was getting an error of 'no module pygame', then I've installed pygame using pip and when I run my program I get this error:

```
[1]    60751 illegal hardware instruction  python pyman.py
[1]    1521 illegal hardware instruction  python pyman.py
```

At first error I thought that pygame would not run on OS X, and than I tried to reinstall it using pip.

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygame in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

SDL is installed:

```
Warning: sdl-1.2.15 already installed
Warning: sdl_image-1.2.12_3 already installed
Warning: sdl_mixer-1.2.12 already installed
Warning: sdl_ttf-2.0.11 already installed
Warning: portmidi-217 already installed
```

I'm using a Mac OS X El Captain, Python 2.7.12 and

Could you enlight me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing pygame is not straight forward in mac. Try these set of instructions:

Create and add the following to ~/.bash_profile:
     # Homebrew binaries now take precedence over Apple defaults
     export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Install Apple Xcode command line tools:
xcode-select --install

Install XQuartz: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Install homebrew:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Install Python3 "proper" and packages we’ll need for installing PyGame from bitbucket:
brew install python3 hg sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi

Install PyGame:
pip3 install (get the pygame link from github) (I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, I hope you understand)

Restart the Mac for Quartz changes

It worked for me. I hope it helps :)

Comment: is it possible to use python2?